# Modifing users in Linux using a script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I trying to modify around 1000 users by removing the "_" from the comment and replacing it with a space.
Here is an example about how one of the user would look:

af1571:x:3571:100:aleja _ fischer:/home/af1571:/bin/bash

I have written a script in bash but it is not working, i think is not going thorough the for loop also, i dont think my usermod command is good as well.

here is what i have so far:

```
#!usr/bin/bash

 FILENAME="/etc/passwd"
 while IFS=: read -r username password userid groupid comment homedir cmdshell
  do

    for i in "{$userid > 1000 && $userid < 2000}"
     do
      usermod $username -c $comment sed "s/_/ /g"

     done
  done< $FILENAME
```

Comment: There are a couple of issues, many of which [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) would point out straight away.

Comment: It runs, it just doesn’t do anything

Comment: If this is what you're actually executing I can't believe that you're not getting error messages from e.g. `usermod`

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU awk `gawk` installed and the `inplace` extension is available there's a fairly easy way to achieve this w/o any looping ...

```
gawk -i inplace -v inplace::suffix=.bak 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{if($3>=1000 && $3<2000){gsub(/_/, " ",$5)}; print }' /etc/passwd
```

If you have only a posix-awk available, this would do it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{if($3>=1000 && $3<2000){gsub(/_/, " ",$5)}; print }' /etc/passwd > ~/passwd.new && mv ~/passwd.new /etc/passwd
```

Given the importance of the file you may want to experiment on a copy of it first to confirm that it works for you ;)

Comment: But in which part of the script i do that?

Comment: @MichaelGarrido Not as part of the script - to replace it. Sorry I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Direct modification of `/etc/passwd` is dangerous.  Races with other programs, and consistency conditions with other files on modern systems, means that special tools like `vipw` and `usermod` should always be used.  See [What command should I run after making changes to /etc/passwd file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102323/264812).

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

getent passwd   \
    |   while IFS=: read -r username _ userid _ comment _ _; do
            (( userid > 1000 ))     || continue
            (( userid < 2000 ))     || continue
            [[ $comment == *_* ]]   || continue

            usermod -c "${comment//_/ }" "$username"
        done
```

- On modern systems `/etc/passwd` may not include all of the valid users.  For instance, users may be configured via LDAP.  The code uses `getent passwd` to get the full list of users.  If you really only want to modify users listed in `/etc/passwd`, replace `getent passwd | while ... done` with `while ... done </etc/passwd`.
- The `_` characters in the `read` arguments cause the corresponding input fields to be discarded.  There's no point putting them in variables because they aren't used.  See [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).
- `[[ $comment == *_* ]] || continue` causes users whose comments don't contain underscores to be skipped.  They don't need to be modified.
- `"${comment//_/ }"` expands to the `$comment` string with all underscores replaced by spaces.  See [Parameter expansion [Bash Hackers Wiki]](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

Comment: `getent passwd {1001..1999}`  gives you users >1000 <2000

Comment: Also, what is the -p for in the first line?

Comment: @MichaelGarrido, the `-p` is to make the code more reliable by insulating it from things in the calling environment that might cause it to behave in unexpected ways.  It disables the reading of "run commands" files (that could define functions or aliases, or change  variables or configurations), shell functions are not inherited from the environment, and some environment that can affect shell behaviour (including `SHELLOPTS`, `BASHOPTS`, `CDPATH`, and `GLOBIGNORE`) are ignored.  Basically, it reduces the likelihood of the "it works on my system" scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Using getent `getent passwd {1001..1999}` list users between 1000 and 2000

Calling cmd `usermod` from awk after modifying  comment `$5` for user `$1` using delimiter `:`

```
getent passwd {1001..1999}|awk -F: '{gsub(/_/," ",$5);print|"usermod "$1" -c \""$5"\""}'
```